# Cannot connect to mail server that requires no authentication: "invalid username / password"

Tags: email, 3.1-honeycomb

I just picked up an Android tablet running 3.1 and am having a nightmare of a time configuring the email settings properly. It's quite embarrassing, really. This is my issue:

I have several POP3 email accounts from domains that I host. I am able to configure the android tablet to receive email from those accounts quite easily. However, I cannot get the bloody thing to connect to the SMTP server. I am in Canada, so port 25 is blocked and I need to use either 26 or 587. I use 26 on both my Linux laptop and my Blackberry. The server does not require authorization so I have that disable on both of the other devices. However, when I try to connect using the Android tablet I keep getting a server error for an invalid username / password. I have unchecked the "Require Sign In" box, so the device should not be trying to authenticate, and I have verified that the service is not asking for authentication. Yet, here I am with an authentication issue.

I know this has to be something ridiculously simple, but for the life of me I can't find it. I'm using the same settings that work on other devices and getting zero love from this tablet. I've tried using 587 and get the same response. I've been all through the settings on the device looking for another place to turn off SMTP authentication but I can't find anything anywhere other than the mail program itself. What am I missing here?

Comment: After you've set up the server and port, if you revisit the settings, do they still show what you've entered? This is a known issue in 4.x: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36776

Comment: The Android mail app might have some bugs, especially because Honeycomb is relatively old and the mail app can't be updated.
Have you tried configuring GMail instead of the stock mail app? You can add POP or IMAP accounts in there too. It has all the features the mail app has, but it still receives updates so bugs are fixed.